# Weird CSS issue with white-space in XSL

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

So I tried to concat the css class name together, here is a snippet of my XSL:

```
<xsl:variable name="btnClass">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$type = 'hello'">myClass</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$type = 'world'">myOtherClass</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>stuff</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="$additionalClass != ''">&#160l<xsl:value-of select="$additionalClass"/></xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

It will give me, for example:

```
myClass extraClass
```

However, inspecting it in HTML, it is actually:

```
myClass&nbsp;extraClass
```

And for that reason, the css never kicked in. If i remove the `&nbsp;` and put an actual space in there, then the class would work as expected.

I tried adjusting my XSL to (using just a regular space):

```
<xsl:if test="$additionalClass != ''"> <xsl:value-of select="$additionalClass"/></xsl:if>
```

But that would only give me:

```
myClassextraClass
```

How can I add a normal space into my string? lol

Comment: Have you tried putting &nbsp; in the xsl? `<xsl:if test="$additionalClass != ''">&nbsp;<xsl:value-of select="$additionalClass"/>`

Comment: I have this on top of my XSL. `<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">]>` so it would just be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pad the extra space with an `xml:text`, like so:

```
  <xsl:if test="$additionalClass != ''">
     <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$additionalClass"/>
  </xsl:if>
```

(Obviously you don't want `&nbsp;` appearing in the `class='x y'` html directly)

You could also use a function like `concat`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', $additionalClass)"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I found out I could use use `<xsl:text> </xsl:text>`. However your second solution is cleaner, so I will use yours instead. :)